# Foundation : How to apply color to a row?

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

I have tried to change color of the row in ZURB Foundation template. I have changed variables `$table-bg` and `$table-even-row-bg`. These modification had no effect. The only way how to modifiy color of the row which I have found is to add the background propertie into CSS Foundation file.

However, I would like to modify color of the row within the `_setting.scss` file of ZURB Foundation.

Does anyone have idea how to changet color of the row?

Comment: `$table-even-row-bg` should do the trick. If this doesn't work for you then you probably have wrong setup of compiling Foundation's SCSS files into CSS. What are you using for compilation? Can you show us your cofiguration if you are using Grunt/Gulp?

Comment: i am using the setup recommended by the zurb-foundation site. I have used the command line: bundle exec compass watch. Compass should compile my code each time there is a modification. Do i am right ?